# SharedPreferences not saving after commit

Tags: java, android

Hi i have the following codes that stores an arraylist into a list then save it into SharedPreference. But when i re-run the app, the values are gone and no matter how many times i invoke adding more elements into the arraylist, it will only invoke once.
The following is my codes:

```
  //debug usage
    Button z = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);
    z.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            testres.add("1");
            testres.add("2");
            testres.add("3");
        }
    });



    SharedPreferences prefs=this.getSharedPreferences("yourPrefsKey", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor edit=prefs.edit();

    Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>();
    set.addAll(testres);
    edit.putStringSet("yourKey", set);
    edit.commit();
```

And this is how i retrieve:

```
 SharedPreferences prefs=this.getSharedPreferences("yourPrefsKey", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    Set<String> set = prefs.getStringSet("yourKey", null);
    List<String> sample= new ArrayList<String>(set);
    testres = new ArrayList<String> (set);

    for(int i =0; i<testres.size();i++){
        System.out.println("Printing: "+testres.get(i));
    }
```

No matter how many times i invoke onclick, the testres will have only 1,2,3 in the arraylist and if i restart the app, the elements in the arraylist is gone. Do advise thank you so much!

**Update:** I managed to retrieve my values on start based on the answers below but still unable to add more elements into the arraylist. The arraylist is stuck with elements 1,2,3 . Do advise.

Comment: Try .apply() instead of commit

Comment: By restart, do you mean, deploy again in debug/run mode from eclipse or quit the application and start from launcher?

Comment: @Eyeball Tried and doesn't work.=/

Comment: @GokulNath close and re-run from menu bro.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> No matter how many times i invoke onclick, the testres will have only
>   1,2,3 in the arraylist and if i restart the app

Because of you are saving values in `SharedPreferences` on Activity start which only save ArrayList with default values.

To save `testres` with items you have added on Button click also use  `SharedPreferences` related code inside onClick method after adding items in ArrayList.

```
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            testres.add("1");
            testres.add("2");
            testres.add("3");
            //... save testres ArrayList in SharedPreferences here
        }
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. Yes im able to retrieve my values on starting the app after doing the suggestion as above but im unable to add more elements into my arraylist no matter how many onclick is invoked. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: @Gene: to add more items in list which you have added in SharedPreferences. first you need to get all values from `SharedPreferences` in ArrayList then add other items in ArrayList with you have retrieved from `SharedPreferences`. let me know if you have any Confusion ?

Comment: Hi, I believe i did it via  List<String> sample= new ArrayList<String>(set);
    testres = new ArrayList<String> (set); Am i doing it wrongly?

Comment: @Gene:  i hope  you know Set always contains non-duplicate items that's why you are getting always `1,2,3`

Comment: @Gene: `set.addAll(testres);` line not adding same items `1,2,3` again in `Set`

Comment: @Gene: My suggestion is instead of using ArrayList for saying multiple values with same key in `SharedPreferences` use `JSONArray` or `JSONObject`.

Comment: Is there any easier alternatives to not use set but something else rather than JSONarray or Object ?

Comment: I didnt know SET does not contains duplicates. Thanks so much! i learnt something new today.

Comment: @Gene: I think no other data-container is allowed in `SharedPreferences`

Answer (score 0):

```
SharedPreferences prefs=this.getSharedPreferences("yourPrefsKey", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor edit=prefs.edit();


Button z = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);
z.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {

        testres.add("1");
        testres.add("2");
        testres.add("3");
        Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>();
set.addAll(testres);
edit.putStringSet("yourKey", set);
edit.commit();
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. Yes im able to retrieve my values on starting the app but im unable to add more elements into my arraylist no matter how many onclick is invoked. Do you have any suggestions?